# c# Telegram API Пост с несколькими картинками и текстом

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

нужно отправить пост с несколькими картинками и текстом.

Как делаю:

```
public async void NewPost(Post post)
{
    botClient = new TelegramBotClient("APIKEY");
    Message[] messages = await botClient.SendMediaGroupAsync(
        chatId: "@dxfnxcvn",
        inputMedia: post.Photo.Select(x => new InputMediaPhoto(x) { Caption = post.Msg})
    );
}
```

Это List изображений `post.Photo`

Добавляю текст: `Caption = post.Msg`

Пост публикуется, но текст виден только если в telegram открыть фото.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы текст был виден под постом нужно что бы `Caption` был указан только для одного изображения, а не для всех, тогда пост будет выглядеть вот так :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как указать `Caption` только для первого изображения со списка?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаньте коллекцию заранее в локальную переменную, добавьте заголовок, и только потом отправляйте

```cs
public async void NewPost(Post post)
{
    var photos = post.Photo.Select(x => new InputMediaPhoto(x)).ToList();
    if (photos.Count > 0)
        photos[0].Caption = post.Msg;
    try
    {
        botClient = new TelegramBotClient("APIKEY");
        Message[] messages = await botClient.SendMediaGroupAsync(
            chatId: "@dxfnxcvn",
            inputMedia: photos
        );
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message); // для async void обязательно обрабатывайте все возможные исключения, иначе вы их просто не увидите
    }
}
```

Кстати, вам наверное не нужно делать `new TelegramBotClient` для каждого сообщения, а сделать экземпляр клиента один раз, и просто переиспользовать его.

Comment: Большое спасибо